# Are shortcodes now allowed in synced blocks?

Tags: block-editor, sync

I am totally, utterly, baffled.

I have been going through the process of remaking reusable (synced) blocks as unsynced, and I suddenly became aware that my shortcodes in synced blocks, which earlier this week weren't working, are today. I have tested this in the main site I am developing and a subsite. And as a test I created some new blocks as synced, with shortcodes, and they worked.

I hadn't been working on my sites for a while, then after I installed the new update (6.3.x, I think), all my shortcodes in synced content stopped working; all I saw was the shortcode text. I saw when searching the problem that WordPress found shortcodes in synced content to be a possible security issue, and quite a few people were tearing their hair out because of this problem.

Was there just an update that cleared this up and re-allowed shortcodes in synced content? I haven't seen notice of an update since the last one I made a few weeks ago that broke my shortcodes. I'm currently on 6.3.2. I haven't installed any plugins that mentioned having a fix for this issue, or that mentioned shortcodes at all.

Now I'm worried about having shortcodes in synced content, and running across the issue again, even though synced blocks are a big time-saver. Has anyone else noticed this?